# When to register/unregister a Broadcast Receiver for a custom View class?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-view

I have a custom class that extends [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). In that class, I want to do a few things based on Broadcasts, so I register a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). **When is the best time to register and unregister a BroadcastReceiver for a custom View implementation?** It doesn't seem as straight forward as an Activity to me.

When I am doing right now is overriding `onWindowVisibilityChanged()`. In there, I check the provided `int visibility` and if it is `VISIBLE` I register. Otherwise, I'll de-register. I am now realizing this is problematic because `onWindowVisibilityChanged()` says this,

> Note that this tells you whether or not your window is being made visible to the window manager; this does not tell you whether or not your window is obscured by  other windows on the screen, even if it is itself visible.

I don't want my BroadcastReceiver receiving Broadcasts if the my View is not visible. Although, I know now that it can be marked as `VISIBLE` but something else on the screen could be in front of it. So, this isn't reliable.

Comment: "In that class, I want to do a few things based on Broadcasts, so I register a BroadcastReceiver" -- FWIW, I think that's an architectural flaw. To me, a custom `View` listening to broadcasts would be like a `Button` reading a file or an `EditText` communicating over HTTP to a Web server. Communicating via broadcasts, file I/O, network I/O, and the like are things that do not belong in the view layer, but elsewhere (e.g., a controller in an MVC-style architecture).

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't totally disagree with you. To try and explain better, one of the things the view does is display the download progress of something. A broadcast is received to know to increment the progress bar of the download for the View.

Comment: "A broadcast is received to know to increment the progress bar of the download for the View" -- IMHO, the broadcast itself should be handled by a controller (activity, fragment, etc.), which then calls a method on the `View` in question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your custom view Activity/Fragment lifecycle-aware, i.e. you have to inform it that onResume()/onPause() happened (or other pair respectively) and register/unregister. I think there is no better way.